# SQL 2 tables area code,number , make 1 table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns , area code and telephone number.

I am setting up  a asterisk server to caller id the numbers, using Microsoft sql

I am attempting to join the tables so that asterisk recieves the number
it can search ie. 7177182222 
and not just the number
717  area code table
7182222 number table

Comment: I dont think I understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT area_code + phone_number AS ten_digit
FROM example_table
```

If your types are not varchar of some sort, you will need to cast them:

```
SELECT CAST(area_code AS VARCHAR(3)) + CAST(phone_number AS VARCHAR(7)) AS ten_digit
FROM example_table
```

Comment: @Andomar, True, but if this is a US-based phone number schema, there isn't an area code or 7-digit prefix that begins with `0`.